# Issues when testing on iPhone 5 on 4inch retina display simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, iphone-5

So i released an app and all seemed fine. All of a sudden I got reviews in and emails that he app did not function and was doing weird things. Turns out the users were using iPhone 4s and 5. I have an iphone 4 running 6.1.3 and everything worked great. As i did some testing in xcode i found using iPhone sim with 3.5 inch screen everything worked perfect. If I switched to the 4 inch retina display it went crazy... button functions from other screens mixed in with current view. Long story short... I went in and fixed it and ran tests using the simulator. all my tools are updated and everything looks good. I released update to iTunes so everyone who had issues could now use the app.

But... a couple people i have been speaking with say the issues are still there. I do not understand how since I test in the simulator. Does anyone know how to properly test an app on the any version iOS and if it works on the sim it will work on an actual device. I am completely baffled by this issue.

I am using xcode 4.6.2 with iOS SDK 6.1 and my app deployment target is 4.3

Comment: Just something to keep in mind, you don't know for sure that these users still experiencing the problem actually installed the update. You wouldn't believe how many people believe that you updating the app means that the update is instantly applied to them.

Comment: I know. I ask them to tell me what version app they are running. And I don't know if it is someone just being a negative person in general or there truly is an issue.